# Reach one concourse task's container from another one

Tags: docker, concourse

```
  - aggregate:
    - task: run-frontend-server # Serve the frontend
      file: devops-repo/pipeline/tasks/serve-client-dist.yml
      image: client-dist-image
    - task: test-frontend # Fire tests at the frontend
      pull: run-frontend-server
      file: devops-repo/pipeline/tasks/test-e2e.yml
      image: docker-registry-protractor
```

Here I want to run protractor tests in one container that fires upp chrome and firefox for frontend testing and in the other container I want to serve the SUT, the page I want to test.

In the task files everything is setup to point to localhost, but as you can see I want to connect to an external container(the first task's container) that serves the webpage. Can this be done from concourse without resorting to docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In concourse, your system under test isn't meant to be run in a task container. Task/build containers are temporary containers spun up with arbitrary networking and file systems, so there's no way to definitively talk between containers.

Further, your task containers could be run on completely different workers, which don't necessarily have the ability to talk to one another.

Instead, you should be talking to some kind of external, permanent integration system, or running your SUT in the same task container as is running the tests.